# Сортировка в MySQL по диапазону цен по группам

Tags: mysql

Нужно сделать следующую выборку-сортировку в MySQL:
Нужно выбрать 10 товаров дороже 100 руб., 10 товаров от 50 до 100 руб., 10 товаров от 30 до 50, 10 товаров от 20 до 30, 10 товаров 10 до 20 и отсортировать их рандомно и выбрать как первые 50 товаров. Далее опять выводим по той же формуле следующие 50 товаров и т.д.

Comment: Дайте пример таблицы с названиями и типами колонок и пример вывода, который должен быть.

Comment: id(AI), title(varchar),price(int). Вывод расписан в вопросе. Сначала должны идти 10 товаров из ценового диапазона >100, далее 10 товаров из диапазона 50-100,далее 10 товаров из диапазона 30-50, далее 10 товаров из диапазона 20-30, далее 10 товаров из диапазона 10-20. Итого 50 записей отсортированных рандомно. После этих снова идут 50 записей по логике описанной выше(записей в таблице больше 10000).

Comment: Да сделайте UNION пяти отдельных запросов. И просто, и понятно, и производительно.

Comment: UNION выберет только 50 первых, а остальные нет.

Comment: А что означает "_Далее опять выводим по той же формуле следующие 50 товаров_" ? Вам в итоге надо что бы выбрало все товары, но отсортировало их так что бы они шли группами по 50 шт в которых по десятку из каждой категории цен ? Тогда это вопрос не о том, как выбирать по 50, а как сортировать так, что бы получилось требуемое. Смысл совершенно другой, ибо нужна правильная формула для order by. И что такое "рандомная сортировка", это всю группу в 50 рандомно перемешать, или рандомно перемешивать 10 одной ценовой категории, ко сами категории при этом выводить последовательно

Comment: P.S. Ну и я бы такое делал все таки на клиенте. На MySQL запрос очень громоздкий с сложно читаемый выйдет, особенно если версия MySQL < 8 (а версию вы вообще не указали, а 8 могла бы упростить запрос раза в 3-4)

Comment: " Вам в итоге надо что бы выбрало все товары, но отсортировало их так что бы они шли группами по 50 шт в которых по десятку из каждой категории цен ?"- ДА." что такое "рандомная сортировка", это всю группу в 50 рандомно перемешать" - ДА. Версия MySQL 8.0.20

Answer (score 0):

Совсем на вскидку с символическими именами, с возможными синтаксическими и логическими ошибками, ввиду того что вы не дали тестовых данных на которых запрос можно было бы отлаживать.

```
select *
  from (
    select t.*, x.num, ceil((row_number() over(partition by x.num))/10 order by rand()) grp10
      from Tab t
      join (select 100 f, 1000000 t, 1 num union select 50, 100, 2 union select 30, 50, 3 ...) x
     where t.цена >= x.f and t.цена < x.t
  ) y
order by grp10, num
```

Основная идея - получаем номера диапазонов цен (num). Назначаем каждой записи номер группы, как целую часть от деления порядкового номера внутри диапазона цен в случайной сортировке на 10. Выводим в порядке номеров групп и номеров ценовых диапазонов. Получаем по 10 записей каждого типа, в порядке расположения типов. Группы по 50 получаются автоматически при достаточном количестве записей. Или попробовать сделать итоговый `order by grp10, rand()` что бы перемешать записи рандомно целиком внутри групп по 50 шт.